# Tika Parser: Exclude PDF Attachments

Tags: pdf, solr, apache-tika

There is a PDF documents that has attachments (here: joboptions) that should not be extracted by Tika. The contents should not be sent to Solr. Is there any way to exclude certain (or all) PDF attachments in the Tika config?

Comment: How are you combining Tika with SOLR? If using Java code (the recommended way), just don't supply a recursing parser!

Comment: Yes, basically in Java code but the default tika config is being used. I cannot determine what the default parser for PDFs is (I assume PDFParser) and I do not see if this parser is recursing or not or how to configure that...

Comment: Without your java code, there's not much we can do to help you!

Comment: The auto detect parser with the default Tika config is being used. I am nut sure what parser is being picked for PDFs under the hood, probably the PDFParser?AutoDetectParser autoDetectParser = new AutoDetectParser(tikaConfig);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a custom `org.apache.tika.extractor.DocumentSelector` and set it at the `ParseContext`. The DocumentSelector is called with metadata of the embedded document to decide whether the embedded document should be parsed.

*Example DocumentSelector:*

```
public class CustomDocumentSelector implements DocumentSelector {

  @Override
  public boolean select(Metadata metadata) {
    String resourceName = metadata.get(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY);
    return resourceName == null || !resourceName.endsWith(".joboptions");
  }
}
```

*Register it at the ParseContext:*

```
parseContext.set(DocumentSelector.class, new CustomDocumentSelector());
```

Answer (score 3):

@gagravarr, we changed that behavior via [TIKA-2096](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2096), Tika 1.15.  The default is now "extract all embedded documents".  To avoid parsing embedded documents call:

`parseContext.set(Parser.class, new EmptyParser())`

Or subclass `EmbeddedDocumentExtractor` to do nothing and send that in via the `ParseContext`.

If you were using Solr DIH's `TikaEntityProcessor`, I'd set `extractEmbedded` to `false`, but you aren't; and please don't. :)

So, I don't think there's an easy way to turn off parsing of embedded documents only for PDFs, and I'm not sure you'd want to.  What if there were an MSWord file attached to a PDF, for example?

If you want to ignore `.joboptions`, you could use a custom `EmbeddedDocumentExtractor`.