# Is there a way to turn off parsing of embedded docs in the tika-server?

Tags: apache-tika, tika-server

I run an unmodified JAX-RS instance of the Apache tika-server 1.22 and use it as an HTTP end-point service that I post files to (mostly Office, PDF and RTF) and get plain-text renditions back with HTTP requests (using the `Accept="text/plain"` header) from our application.

Since Tika 1.15, the default behaviour is now to "extract all embedded documents" [TIKA-2096](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2096).

I want to be able to turn this behaviour off on our tika-server so that embedded documents are NOT extracted and I only get the text rendition of the main document contents.

Is it possible to do this via a `tika-config.xml` file, or do I need to do a custom build and subclass `EmbeddedDocumentExtractor` so that it doesn't do anything?

An answer to [tika-parser-exclude-pdf-attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817271/tika-parser-exclude-pdf-attachments) indicates that you can turn this behaviour off by subclassing `EmbeddedDocumentExtractor`, but I'd like to check if it's possible to do this via `tika-config.xml` without having to do a custom build of the tika-server.

I have looked at [Configuring Tika](http://tika.apache.org/1.22/configuring.html) but there is no mention of embedded docs here.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Comment: Not until just now - the `X-Tika-Skip-Embedded: true` header setting that @dave-meikle has added to Tika 1.25 looks very promising. Will test it out when released and update this question then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers in [tika-parser-exclude-pdf-attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817271/tika-parser-exclude-pdf-attachments) are excellent for if you are calling Tika via code.

Previously there hasn't been a way to do this for embedded files in Tika Server, other than disabling the whole file type using *EmptyParser* with something like the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <parsers>
        <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.EmptyParser">
            <mime-exclude>image/jpeg</mime-exclude>
            <mime-exclude>application/zip</mime-exclude>
        </parser>
    </parsers>
</properties>
```

This has become a common request, so I've added a feature coming up in Tika 1.25 (yet to be released) to allow for the skipping embedded files using a header setting:

```
curl -T test_recursive_embedded.docx http://localhost:9998/tika --header "Accept: text/html" --header "X-Tika-Skip-Embedded: true"
```

Any parser using the *EmbeddedDocumentExtractor* will honour this.

Comment: Tika 1.25 was released on 30th November.  We've tested the new "X-Tika-Skip-Embedded" header when calling tika end-point to extract text from docs with embedded docs, and it works a treat.  Thank you Dave.

Comment: One question I do have - when doing a multipart POST to /tika/form, this new header appears to be ignored.  Is that expected?

Comment: Glad to hear the new feature helps. Not sure how you are calling this but from looking at the code, it reads the attachment headers so a call like this passes it on:

`curl -F "upload=@testMif.mif;headers='X-Tika-Skip-Embedded: true'" http://localhost:9998/tika/form`

IIRC you need a modern version of curl to try this (above 7.58 or 7.59).

Comment: Yes, I figured that after reading the code too.  We are calling the Tika service endpoint from a Java application with HttpClient - I have changed the existing multi-part POST request to a simpler PUT request and it all works as expected.